# Pandas object with timestamps to string

Tags: python, pandas, string, python-object

I have a pandas dataframe with a column `iso` in `datetime64[ns]` format.  My goal is to first convert this column to the ISO 8601 format, and then to a plain string.

```
dtrain.shape
(10886, 12)

dtrain.dtypes
season                 int64
holiday                int64
workingday             int64
weather                int64
temp                 float64
atemp                float64
humidity               int64
windspeed            float64
casual                 int64
registered             int64
count                  int64
iso           datetime64[ns]
```

I have tried a few methods mentioned on StackOverflow, which throw errors:

```
dtrain['iso'].astype(datetime)
dtrain['iso'].tolist()/1e9
```

The following works, but converts the column to a Python object which contains both formats and cannot be converted to string with `str()` or `as.type('str')`

```
dtrain['iso'] =dtrain['iso'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%:%SZ')
dtrain['iso'].dtype
dtype('O')
dtrain['iso'] = dtrain['iso'].astype('str')
dtrain['iso']


datetime
2011-01-01 00:00:00    2011-01-01T00:00:00Z
2011-01-01 01:00:00    2011-01-01T01:00:00Z
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2011-01-01T02:00:00Z
2011-01-01 03:00:00    2011-01-01T03:00:00Z
2011-01-01 04:00:00    2011-01-01T04:00:00Z
                               ...         
2012-12-19 19:00:00    2012-12-19T19:00:00Z
2012-12-19 20:00:00    2012-12-19T20:00:00Z
2012-12-19 21:00:00    2012-12-19T21:00:00Z
2012-12-19 22:00:00    2012-12-19T22:00:00Z
2012-12-19 23:00:00    2012-12-19T23:00:00Z
Name: iso, Length: 10886, dtype: object
```

What is the workaround to convert a pandas dataframe object column to a string column (containing only the ISO 8601 format) in this case?

Comment: strings and objects are the same thing in pandas. What is your goal? There is no "string" dtype in pandas -- just object which can be made up of only strings or of mixed data types. Please see the first table in this link: https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html

Comment: my goal is for the object to contain only the ISO format